# Make a div in a grid stretch to full height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a very simple grid layout of the menu, header, and content.

I would like the content (blue box) to stretch vertically. As you can see, the grid element (yellow box) already stretches vertically, but the blue element inside of it (which should be dynamic content) does not.

Is there a way to achieve this 1) without switching the whole grid structure to flexbox and 2) without using calc to give the blue content 100vh minus the header height?

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "menu header" "menu content";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mainMenuWrapper {
  grid-area: menu;
  height: auto;
}

.headerWrapper {
  grid-area: header;
  height: auto;
}

.contentWrapper {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: ???
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainMenuWrapper">
    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerWrapper">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image:
[image]

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/the2sj1n/3/

Comment: have you tried height:100%;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `height: 100%` on that blue box `.content`

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /*Removed unexpected margins from browsers' default styles*/
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "menu header" "menu content";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mainMenuWrapper {
  grid-area: menu;
  height: auto;
}

.headerWrapper {
  grid-area: header;
  height: auto;
}

.contentWrapper {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /*The change here*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainMenuWrapper">
    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerWrapper">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG It's actually not supposed to work, I tried it in my real project of course, but here it's working you're right, I'm sorry I probably did something wrong, I will check thanks a lot

Comment: Yes I had one extra div in my chain so it didn't allow the 100% height to make it stretch anyways thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome!~ If you think my answer is useful, could you mark it as your question's solution? It will give me a little support for this community as well as me. I'll also really appreciate it :D @sir-haver

Comment: Yes of course it asked me to wait a few mins now I marked it(: